# What is the difference between a normal compiler error and a fatal compiler error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

For example:

**Normal Compiler Error**:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\mystermini\main.cpp(1066) : error C2065: 'break_me' : undeclared identifier
```

**Fatal Error**:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\mystermini\main.cpp(1050) : fatal error C1016: #if[n]def expected an identifier
```

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota: yes, duplicate it is!